# Reporting Services Printing Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssrs, ssrs-2014

Whenever we apply a patch (recently with CU5), end users need are prompted for administrator credentials to print. In googling, I see many different suggestions, but nothing seems to work.

I have tried adding the SSRS server to the trusted sites list. Also, I have checked the active X permissions and they seem to be set correctly under Security Settings.

Does anyone know the necessary configuration to avoid this prompt with future SQL Server updates on our SSRS server?

I've followed the Microsoft [directions for RSClientPrint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/enable-and-disable-client-side-printing-for-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15&redirectedfrom=MSDN&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014) - in looking at the users Internet Security settings, they appear to be in line with those recommendations.

[image: UAC Prompts]
[image: Resulting Error Message]

Comment: did you ever figure this out?